# C# encryption and decryption IV issue

Tags: c#, encryption, file-io, cryptography

My code performs encryption but not decryption. I wanted it to generate random IV so made some changes, but now it's not decrypting. I think I am messing up with IV. It doesn't seem that it is able to decrypt properly.

The IV is not getting prefixed to the encrypted file or the decrypt method is unable to find IV. I can't understand how to solve it. The file is produced for example I encrypted a text file which had "hello world", after encryption it produced some gibberish. After decryption it produced a empty text file.

encryption method:

```
private const ushort ITERATIONS = 1300;
private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c };

private static byte[] CreateKey(string password, int keySize)
{
    DeriveBytes derivedKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT, ITERATIONS);
    return derivedKey.GetBytes(keySize >> 3);
}


public static void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
{

    // First we are going to open the file streams 
    FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(file+"enc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

    // Then we are going to derive a Key and an IV from the
    // Password and create an algorithm 
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);


    // passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    AES.GenerateIV();
    AES.Key = CreateKey(password, AES.KeySize);
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(file.Length)) 
        memStream.Write(AES.IV, 0, 16);

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    int bufferLen = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
    int bytesRead;

    do
    {
        // read a chunk of data from the input file 
        bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

        // encrypt it 
        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead != 0);

    // close everything 

    // this will also close the unrelying fsOut stream
    cs.Close();
    fsIn.Close();

}
```

decryption method:

```
private const ushort ITERATIONS = 1300;
private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c };

private static byte[] CreateKey(string password, int keySize)
{
    DeriveBytes derivedKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT, ITERATIONS);
    return derivedKey.GetBytes(keySize >> 3);
}


public static void DecryptFile(string fileIn, string Password)
{

    // First we are going to open the file streams 
    FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileIn);
    string result = fileIn.Substring(0, fileIn.Length - extension.Length);

    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(result,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);



  //  passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    fsIn.Read(iv, 0, 16);
    AES.IV=iv;

    AES.Key = CreateKey(Password, AES.KeySize);
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;


    // Now create a crypto stream through which we are going
    // to be pumping data. 
    // Our fileOut is going to be receiving the Decrypted bytes. 
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut,
        AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Now will will initialize a buffer and will be 
    // processing the input file in chunks. 
    // This is done to avoid reading the whole file (which can be
    // huge) into memory. 
    int bufferLen = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
    int bytesRead;

    do
    {
        // read a chunk of data from the input file 
        bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

        // Decrypt it 
        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    } while (bytesRead != 0);

    // close everything 
    cs.Close(); // this will also close the unrelying fsOut stream 
    fsIn.Close();

}
```

Comment: Actually am I missing something here Is it even a issue with IV (all I wanted was that IV should be random and now decryption broke) Is the error caused due to something else?

Comment: Are you sure are using 128 bit encryption and not 256 bits?

Comment: The Rijndael `LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize` is 256-bits and the `LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize` is also 256-bits. It is the latter that is incorrect. It is always better to specify all values and not use defaults.

Comment: You're not clear about your *"decryption issue"*. Are there exceptions? If so, please include them in your question. If not, then a file must be produced. If so, how does the file differ from the file that you expected? If zaph's answer is correct, then the first 32 bytes must have been completely different and the rest of the file ok. Please confirm.

Comment: the file is produced for example I encrypted a text file which had "hello world" , after encryption it produced some gibberish. after decryption it produced a empty text file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify a block size of 128-bits (16-bytes) for the encryption to be AES, see options below:

Generally the iv is the same size as the block size. You are supplying a 16-byte iv and the Rijndael maximum block size is 32-bytes so there is a very good chance that the encryption routines are using an additional 16-bytes of junk bytes following the iv.

There are a few problems: The class is Rijndael and AES is a subset of Rijndael so allowable parameters of Rijndael may not be allowable for AES.

1. `LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize` will return the maximum Rijndael block size of 256-bits but AES has a fixed block size of 128-bits. Thus you are not actually using AES. You must specify a block size of 128-bits (16-bytes).
2. `PaddingMode.Zeros` will not work if the last byte of the data to be encrypted is a `0x00` byte. Generally PKCS#7 (archaically PKCS#5) is used, PHP mcrypt excepted. -- Thanks to ArtjomB.

As prompted by ArtjomB.
If I am correct there are two options,choose one of the options:

1: Change the block size to 16-bytes as required by AES:
Change to encryption and decryption:

```
AES.BlockSize = 128;
```

2: Use a 32-byte iv (note that this will not produce AES encryption):
Change to encryption:

```
memStream.Write(AES.IV, 0, 32);
```

Change to decryption:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[32];
fsIn.Read(iv, 0, 32
```

Comment: @panman Read the first two paragraphs again, where zaph provided the best guess.

Comment: regarding 2nd point where I have to use 32 byte IV, do I need to do it even if I change the block size? or what

Comment: Choose either 1 or 2, I suggest option 1.

Comment: Yup , it works ..although I had to make these changes.. in encryption: "fsOut.Write(AES.IV, 0, 16);" and in decryption: "byte[] iv = new byte[16]; fsIn.Read(iv, 0, 16);" is it valid or will it destroy the purpose of randomness of IV

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Building on the results of zaph's answer...</sup>

You need to write the IV to the file, not to some temporary MemoryStream that you're never using:

```
fsOut.Write(AES.IV, 0, 32);
```

And completely remove the line `using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(file.Length))`.

This seems be the issue when reading in the comments:

> the file is produced for example I encrypted a text file which had "hello world" , after encryption it produced some gibberish. after decryption it produced a empty text file

This means that the actual ciphertext is empty and there is nothing to decrypt. The happens, because the IV wasn't actually written to the ciphertext file and therefore the decryption method thought that the single block that is present in there is actually the IV.

Don't forget to read the full IV from the ciphertext file during decryption:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[32];
fsIn.Read(iv, 0, 32)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply.I will update result after making the changes

Comment: Yup , it works ..although I had to make these changes..
in encryption:
"fsOut.Write(AES.IV, 0, 16);"

and in decryption:

byte[] iv = new byte[16];
fsIn.Read(iv, 0, 16)

is it valid or will it destroy the purpose of randomness of IV

Comment: I assume you've made the changes, because you set `AES.BlockSize = 128;`. In that case, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you so much btw you and zaph both provided me with same answers..thank you both so much ..have a great day